# how to split string into array on commas but ignore commas in parentheses

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have a string with 3 lines:

```
a VARCHAR(20),
b FLOAT, c FLOAT,
d NUMBER(38,0), e NUMBER(38,0)
```

Need to split a string into array based on comma delimiter but to ignore commas in parentheses.

Final output is array with 5 elements:

```
s_arr = ['a VARCHAR(20)', 'b FLOAT', 'c FLOAT', 'd NUMBER(38,0)', 'e NUMBER(38,0)']
```

So far I have `s_arr = s.split(",")`

How to achieve that?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be no space next to the comma contained in the parenthesis?

Comment: Probably yes.. Need to check all different strings that are coming but 90% sure - yes.

Comment: Good try but the first line does not have `, ` -> it has comma followed by newline.

Comment: If you are serious about nested brackets, you should split like this: [`re.split(r',\n*(?=(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)`](https://ideone.com/3htUeD)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  may use [`,(?![^\(]*[\)])`](https://regex101.com/r/BfRFvS/1) with a list comprehension:

```
s = '''
a VARCHAR(20),
b FLOAT, c FLOAT,
d NUMBER(38,0), e NUMBER(38,0)
'''

[i.strip() for i in re.split(r',(?![^\(]*[\)])', s)]
# ['a VARCHAR(20)', 'b FLOAT', 'c FLOAT', 'd NUMBER(38,0)', 'e NUMBER(38,0)']
```

Comment: this won't work if there are nested parens.  "foo (bar, baz())" splits as ['foo (bar', 'baz())']

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Regular Expression to split based on multiple delimiters

```
stringToSplit = '''a VARCHAR(20),
b FLOAT, c FLOAT,
d NUMBER(38,0), e NUMBER(38,0)'''

import re
re.split(', |,\n', stringToSplit)
```

This works because your string doesn't have any spaces or newlines after commas in the parentheses `(1,2)`.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name

Comment: My bad, I've been using javascript lately @user3483203

Comment: Almost there.. does not work if there is space inside parens.

Comment: @Joe yes that is explained in the answer, as your strings don't seem to have spaces inside the parentheses.

Comment: Yes but that is 90% chance - someone asked for it. Accepted answer that takes care of that as well..

Answer (score 0):

If you know more about the data, you can easily avoid all the weird parsing by doing this:

```
a.replace(", ", "@").replace(",\n", "@").split("@")
```

Which replaces the delimiters with a different character and splits them on that.
This assumes you have a space after the comma for delimiters.  Not the most elegant, but will handle most cases if you're in a bind.

Comment: Should work now, I didn't realize the new lines were in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions and string methods:

**Given**

```
s = """\
a VARCHAR(20),
b FLOAT, c FLOAT,
d NUMBER(38,0), e NUMBER(38,0)
"""
```

**Code**

```
[z.strip() for y in [x.split(", ") for x in s.split(",\n")] for z in y]
# ['a VARCHAR(20)', 'b FLOAT', 'c FLOAT', 'd NUMBER(38,0)', 'e NUMBER(38,0)']
```

Alternatively

```
[z.strip(",") for y in [x.split(", ") for x in s.splitlines()] for z in y]
# ['a VARCHAR(20)', 'b FLOAT', 'c FLOAT', 'd NUMBER(38,0)', 'e NUMBER(38,0)']
```